# Get attribute in Import ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

Im using `sucrase` to use ES6 modules in NodeJS and i have a code that your import works differently depending on your export.
if I use `module.exports` to export the lib, when i use `import obj, { auth } from 'someLib'`(ES6) its possible use the `auth` and if use `export default` to export the code `auth` is `undefined`
Example:

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'jefter',
  lastName: 'Rocha',
  age: 24,
  auth: {
    login: 'jefter123',
    password: '123pwd'
  }
}

import obj, { auth } from 'someLib'
console.log(auth)


result: { login: 'jefter123', password: '123pwd' }
```

case I use `export default` to export the code, the `console.log` returns `undefined`

Comment: Note that `module.exports` is _not_ ES Module syntax at all, and will not work in a way that lets you `import` its data. it's Node.js's module object export convention (typically referred to as "commonjs") and uses `require(...)` as its import statement.

Comment: well im using this way in may code and its works haha! i'm using `sucrase` to use ES6 modules...

Comment: Uh, yes, don't use `export default` when you want `import { auth } from …` to work. Instead, for that do `export const auth = …;`.